# filter operator in rxjs and subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

i am working in an Angular Material Dialog, what i want to do is a patch request when i close the Dialog.

In my component i have a property that like this, with a certain data i receive with @input

```
  public stat:Stat = {
    id: "",
    _id: "",
    name: "",
    bithplace: "",
    institution: "",
    topics: [],
    maininterest: "",
    img: "",
    index: ''
  }
```

I want to filter the data so i can get only the properties that changed and the index to make the patch request.

```
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogUpdateComponent, dialogConfig)
    dialogRef.afterClosed()
    .pipe(
      filter( (resp) => Object.values(resp) !== Object.values(this.stat) && resp.index)
    )
    .subscribe
    (resp => this.statService.editStat(resp, resp.index))
  }
```

At this point i think i should have the data i want, but when i execute the code nothing happens.

This is the editStat method:

```
  editStat(stat: Stat, index:string):Observable<Stat>{
    return this.http.patch<Stat>(`${this.basic_URL}/${index}`,stat)
  }
```

When i make the patch request in Postman, changing a property in the body it works, but this doesnt happen in my app when i close the dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observables need subscribed to. What you're missing is the subscribe. Best way to handle that is to concatMap over to it.

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogUpdateComponent, dialogConfig)
  dialogRef.afterClosed()
  .pipe(
  filter( (resp) => Object.values(resp) !== Object.values(this.stat) && resp.index)),
  concatMap((resp) => this.statService.editStat(resp, resp.index)),
)
.subscribe();
```

Comment: thank you!! but can you please explain why is it necessary the concatMap? i saw this example in the rxjs documentation:  `const example = source.pipe(filter(num => num % 2 === 0)); ` and then  `const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(Even number: ${val}));`

Comment: Sure! When you want one observable to return a value, and then wait for the next observable, you use concatMap. 
I mentioned that we need to subscribe - the concatMap keeps you within the same pipe and chains all observables under the same subscribe.